# What will be the circumference of circle in this question?

Tags: geometry

i solved this question but my answer is not exactly as given in options of the question. so please give full solution and exact answer as in given in image.

"six circles each of unit radius are being circumscribed by another larger circle. all the smaller circles touch each other. what is the circumference of the larger circle."

answer is 4 root 3 pie centimeter[image: image for this question no. 4]

Thanks

Comment: Why not show us how you did the problem, and maybe we'll see whether there's a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Let the centers of the lower left vertex circle be $O_1$, horizontally next to it is the circle with center $O_2$, horizontally next to the latter is circle $O_3$, then we go analogously up to denote the centers of the next two consecutive circles by $O_4$ and $O_5$ and the center of the last circle is $O_6$, i.e. the center of the second, different from $O_2$, circle tangent to the circle with center $O_1$. The vertex circles have centers $O_1, O_3, O_5$ forming an equilateral triangle and the points $O_2, O_4, O_6$ are the midpoints of the corresponding edges of the triangle $O_1O_3, O_3O_5, O_5O_1$. Therefore the three segments $O_1O_4, \, O_3O_6, \, O_5O_2$ intersect at the centroid $O$ of the triangle $O_1, O_3, O_5$. The centroid $O$ is the center of the large circle tangent to the three circles with centers $O_1, O_3, O_5$. The radius $R$ of that large tangent circle is $R=|OO_1|+1$.  As $O$ is the centroid of the equilateral triangle $O_1, O_3, O_5$ it follows that $|OO_1|=\frac{2}{3}|O_1O_4|$ while $|O_1O_4|=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|O_1O_3|=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}4=2\sqrt{3}$. Thus $|OO_1|=\frac{2}{3}2\sqrt{3}=  \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$ and therefore $R=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}+1=\frac{4+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}$. The circumference of the large tangent circle is $2\large(\frac{4+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}\large)\pi$.