# what will be radius of circle in this question?

Tags: geometry

Q.There are 2 spherical balls touching each other at a point P. They both are kept on the ground and the point P is 10 cm above the ground. The radius of one circle is 8 cm. Find the radius of the other circle.

i am getting 13 as answer[image: image of question]

Comment: What? You've solved your question. What do you still not know?

Comment: sir i am not sure about this answer.

Comment: You're getting exactly 13?

Comment: yes exactly 13. if i use similarity of triangle rules.

Answer (score 2):

By similar triangles,
$$\frac{AD}{DE} = \frac{AB}{BC}$$
$AD = 8$, as it is the radius of the smaller circle. $DE = 10 - 8 = 2$ based on the information given. Let $r$ be the larger radius; then $AB = 8+r$, $BC = r-8$. Thus, we have
$$4 = \frac{r+8}{r-8}$$
$$4r-32 = r+8$$
$$3r=40$$
$$r = \frac{40}{3}$$

Comment: thanks sir @florence but i did it  as AD/AC = DE/BC and i was getting answer 13. was it wrong?

Comment: AD and AC arent sides of the same trianglem, nor are they corresponding sides of the two triangles.

Comment: sir please take a look also at this question
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890123/what-will-be-the-circumference-of-circle-in-this-question

Answer (score 2):

Let $BD=x, AD=8$. Then $BC=x-8, DE=10-8=2$.

$$\triangle ADE \sim \triangle ABC \Rightarrow \frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{DE}{BC}$$
$$\frac8{8+x}=\frac2{x-8}$$
Then $x=\frac{40}3$